# Laravel API throttle issue in AWS auto-scaling architecture

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have recently migrated the Laravel Application to AWS auto-scaling architecture. Now, I am facing an API throttle exception. Error is mentioned below. This throttle does not use to come when I had a single server. API throttle can be increased by editing `kernal.php`. But I want to know if the increasing throttle is the best solution for the auto-scaling architecture problems. Is there anything alternative or best solution for this?

**NOTE:** My problem, for now, is fixed after increasing throttle in `Kernel.php`.

> exception: "Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException"
> file:
> "/var/www/html/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php"
> line: 124 message: "Too Many Attempts."

Comment: I'm more of the opinion that the rate limit should reflect what you deem as legitimate traffic patterns to your website. It shouldn't be based on server capabilities now that you are on auto-scaling.

Answer (score 1):

your solution is a correct answer but that's not where you should put it.
you could use [GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle#usage) to change the throttle on API your calls.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)